# Support several interface orientations but stay locked in portrait mode

Tags: rotation, viewcontroller, autorotate, locked

I need a way to do the above. I've tried putting

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

into every one of my viewcontrollers, but it still autorotates when I tilt the device on its side.

Why do I need this? One of our partners has an SDK which requires us to support the other orientations (or else their app crashes).

So what can I do to lock our portrait mode in place and keep it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a category to extend and override the UITabBarController, forcing autorotation off.

Check out this SO:
[UITabBarController Rotation Issues in ios 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522903/uitabbarcontroller-rotation-issues-in-ios-6)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. In iOS "supporting" a device orientation implies that when the screen rotates to one of the other orientations (not portrait) your application re-sizes and lays out for that orientation. If you want to remain locked in portrait mode DO NOT support anything other than portrait.

Comment: This is not what I wanted to hear, but I'm glad you told me before I went any further. If I dont' get any other hopeful replies soon, I'll mark your's as the answer.

Comment: If their Lib is crashing Apps not supporting other orientations, THEY have a bug which THEY should fix. And fixing it does NOT constitute asking other people to support other orientations. Are the using a TabController?