# UIInterfaceOrientation in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

In my application i got 2 `UIViewControllers`, first is root controller in `UINavigationController` and second is called by first one by pushing to `UINavigationController's` stack.

So first view should be only in portrait orientation, when second should support all orientations.

I wrote in first this code:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

But it still rotating to all orientations. Why?

Comment: Try using new iOS SDK 6.0 autorotation methods : `shouldAutorotate` , `supportedInterfaceOrientations` , `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`

Comment: @George still nothing ((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use `uinavigationcontroller`, but instead used `presentmodalviewcontroller`. This allowed me to use different orientation management.

Answer (score 0):

May i know what IOS version you are using? This method is deprecated for IOS 6

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

Please check following URL the voted answer is some what you might be looking for

[UITabBarController Rotation Issues in ios 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522903/uitabbarcontroller-rotation-issues-in-ios-6/12526152#12526152)

Answer (score 0):

I create category for `UINavigationController`. it described here

[How to force a UIViewController to Portrait orientation in iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520030/how-to-force-a-uiviewcontroller-to-portait-orientation-in-ios-6)

Answer (score 0):

Best way for you to do this is change the Supported orientations in the APP summary to the ones you like (Portrait orientation) only.

[image]

Then you can handle the other pages orientation delegate methods.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
return YES;
```

}

-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
NSInteger mask = 0;
if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight])
    mask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft])
    mask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait])
    mask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
if ([self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown])
    mask |= UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
return mask;
}

Comment: if i choose only portrait orientation in Summary, nothing rotate ((

Comment: Here is the trick. If you set the Portrait mode only in App summary, App will launch in the portrait mode and then you can handle the orientation changes in any of the view controllers and it will work accordingly. If you are trying it in device, please make sure, your orientation lock is switched off.

Comment: Can you also please check if you are making any changes to the status bar orientation?