# SLComposeViewController auto rotation

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, slcomposeviewcontroller, autorotate

I have a UIViewController which is always in landscape orientation. I present an instance of SLComposeViewController but to my surprise this results in autorotation of both my view controller to portrait mode along with my instance of SLComposeViewController. How do I stop this autorotation from happening ? Is SLComposeViewController only supported in portrait mode ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rewriting an existing post, I will give you a link to another post that has the code. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108210/autorotation-lock-programmatically). The individual did a good work on explaining it as well.

Please view the second anwser by klkl